# Knockout - Pausable Array not working

Tags: knockout.js

I am using knockout pausable from this page: https://github.com/Areson/Knockout-Extensions/wiki/Knockout.Pausable

It works perfectly on observables however I can't get it to work with observable arrays. The array is declared as follows:

```
 var itemModel = function () {
          var me = this;
          me.Key = ko.observable(0).extend({ pauseable: true });
          me.Value = ko.observable('').extend({ pauseable: true });

      };

 me.testArray = ko.observableArray().extend({ pauseable: true });
```

when I use :
    me.testArray.pause();
and 
    me.testArray.resume();

it does not have any effect.

Here is the link to JS fiddle with the full example:

http://jsfiddle.net/almir/TTsZ5/

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm only assuming here, but pausing an observableArray will pause the binding of when you add or remove items, not when you modify the properties of the items in the array.

Comment: Right on the spot there, so will need to iterate through the items in order to pause/resume them

Comment: Correct. Or remove the old item, modify it, then add it back in again or something perhaps? It would depend on performance etc and why you are actually needing the pause.